# How do I Modify JLabels in a Window without ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, jframe, jlabel

I have a question about JLabels. I am trying to program an application that has a window (Set up with JFrame.) with many JLabels. Anyway, I was wondering if there was a way I could have the window show, then modify the JLabels' text. The problem I am having is that the window won't show up until the program reaches the end of the class. Is there a way I can get around that? Do I have to use a Thread? If so, how would I do that.
Thanks,
  ~Rane

Example:

```
public class Start extends JFrame{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  Random random = new Random();

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");

  panel.add(label);
  add(panel);

  while(true){
    int rnd = random.nextInt(4);
    label.setText("" + rnd);
  }

} // I want to do that, but the window won't show until the loop ends. In this case, the loop
  // never will end. How would I do something like this if not the same exact thing?
```

Comment: Did you consider placing a timer to allow you to read new labels?? (followed by refreshing the frame)

Comment: Yes. Without using a thread though, the program still waits for the timer to finish.

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call setVisibile in the constructor before you enter the while loop.

```java
public class Start extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Start() {
        Random random = new Random();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");

        panel.add(label);
        add(panel);

        this.setVisible(true); //IMPORTANT PART

        while(true){
            int rnd = random.nextInt(4);
            label.setText("" + rnd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more on why this approach is incorrect; [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the fact that Swing is not thread safe and that all interactions and modifications to the UI should be made within the contentext of the Event Dispatching Thread.

This also means that you never perform any long running or time consuming actions within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, as this will prevent it from processing new event placed on the `EventQueue`, including, repaint requests.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

The simplest solution would be to use a `javax.swing.Timer`.  This will allow you to schedule a regular call back which is guaranteed to be triggered within the context of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class RandomLabels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RandomLabels();
    }

    public RandomLabels() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private Random rnd;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel();
            add(label);

            rnd = new Random();

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setText(Integer.toString(rnd.nextInt()));
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

This also means you can control the `Timer`, starting it and stopping it when you want/need to with ease.

You could use a `Thread`, but the management requirements increase...You become responsible for managing the synchronisation of the updates to the UI, as well as having to implement functionality to actually stop the thread.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class RandomLabels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RandomLabels();
    }

    public RandomLabels() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private Random rnd;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel();
            add(label);

            rnd = new Random();

            Thread t = new Thread(new Randomizer());
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public class Randomizer implements Runnable {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                label.setText(Integer.toString(rnd.nextInt()));
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(40);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Another (better than using a `Thread`) solution might be to use a `SwingWorker`.  Which would allow you to perform long running/blocking/time consuming actions within the background, but provides functionality to easily send updates back to the UI automatically.

Take a closer look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

And finally, take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).  You must ensure that you UI is started/constructed within the context of the EDT as well...